# Modx: How can i add charts and profile update progress bar in modx user panel?

Tags: extjs, modx, modx-revolution

I want to add profile progress bar, and charts using database data in modx user panel. I didnt get any documentation on that. Is there any way to do that on modx?

Answer (score 1):

I also don't have a ready to use solution, but some time ago I wrote a short tutorial about how to show 'front-end content' on  your dashboard. See http://forums.modx.com/thread/87637/tutorial-how-to-get-content-in-a-dashboard-widget-using-getresources

In this example I used getResources, but you can also use [Rowboat](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/rowboat), so you can grab info from the MODX database and mould it in a chart.